# Merge all the [override] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

The tags [override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/override), [overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overriding), and [method-overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-overriding) all have the **exact same** tag wiki. There is also [overrides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overrides) with a very similar description and [function-overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-overriding) which does not have a tag wiki.

I suggest all of these tags are made synonyms with the most popular, [override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/override) as the parent tag.

Comment: [tag:method-overriding] is more specific, it wouldn't be a good idea to dissolve it into the more generic tags. I can't spot any difference in usage between [tag:override] and [tag:overriding], I think these two can be merged. The tag wiki for that tag should be updated to discuss the general concept of overriding and refer to [tag:method-overriding] when it's methods that are being overridden, or alternatively [tag:override]/[tag:overriding] should be manually split into more specific tags, I'm not sure which.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with [Gilles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250984/merge-all-the-override-tags#comment1318_250984): [method-overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-overriding) is probably a bit too specific to be merged directly into [override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/override), but [override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/override) and [overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overriding) refer to the same fundamental concept, with no need for distinct tags, so these should be merged.

...and they now are: [overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overriding) → [override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/override) is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

I'm refraining from applying the status to the question as a whole, though, because [method-overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-overriding) still needs to be cleaned up.